# Iterating through a lot of records using Sequel, with an eager-loaded association

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Basically... How to do it?

Yes, the docs say that `each` does not make sense with `eager`, but that sentence only makes sense when records are loaded one by one - not in bulks of 1000 typically where skipping N+1 queries really has a big impact.

I use postgres with following extensions:

```
Sequel.extension :core_extensions
Sequel.extension :pg_json
Sequel.extension :pg_json_ops

DB.extension(:pagination)

Sequel::Model.plugin :timestamps, update_on_create: true
```

if I try `use_cursor.each` then the eager loading is not used.

If I try pagination and `each_page` the eager loading is also not used.

If I try just `all.each` then eager loading kicks in, so I know I got the `eager` call right.

What do you do?

Comment: I always eager load in batches (of say 1000 at a time). Pagination makes it easy to to do batches https://github.com/chanks/sequel-seek-pagination

Comment: Are you loading or unloading records?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I expanded the OP with the extensions list used by my code, are you sure that the `sequel-seek-pagination` actually performs the eager load when postgres + common adapters are used? Unless you are monitoring the SQL logs you would not notice that something broke here, the "joined" records would simply be lazy loaded?

Comment: @mwp, what do you mean exactly? :) I'm writing an export script if that helps :)